# What is the smallest positive integer that can not be written as a sum of positive integer powers of distinct elements of {1,…,n}?

Tags: exponentiation

Lets say you have numbers from 1 to 3, how many numbers can be made using powers of the numbers without the base repeating?
$1=1^1$
$2=2^1$
$3=3^1$
$4=3^1+1^1$
$5=3^1+2^1$
$6=3^1+2^1+1^1$
$7=3^1+2^2$
$8=2^3$
$9=3^2$
$10=3^2+1^1$
$11=3^2+2^1$
$12=3^2+2^1+1^1$
$13=3^2+2^2$
$14=3^2+2^2+1^1$
The answer is 14 because 15 cannot be made without 2 base numbers repeating
What I'm asking is. Using the sum of powers with the base of 1 to n, without a base repeat. How many numbers can you make?

Comment: Can the exponents be as large as $n$ or still just $3$?

Comment: @Karl as large as n

Comment: So would it be accurate to rephrase your question as: What is the smallest positive integer that can not be written as a sum of positive integer powers of distinct elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: Your question is not totally clear.  From your title, example and reply to Karl, you would appear to be asking for any given $\ n\ $ what is the largest number $\ x\ $ such that all natural numbers $\ k\ $ from $1$ to $x$ can be written in the form
$$
k=\sum_{i=1}^ra_i^{b_i}
$$
where $\ 1\le a_i\le n\ $, $\ 1\le b_i\le n\ $ and $\ a_i\ne a_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ $. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you also try it for $n=4$ ?

Comment: @peter Not yet.

Comment: yes @lonzaleggiera

Comment: yes, I will change the title to that. @Karl